# django result of annotate doesn't include in serializers

Tags: python, django

### Django 2.2

I'm serializing a Queryset to use AJAX.

This is my simple code

```py
def datatables_ajax_test_api(request):
    users_object = User.objects.filter(created_gte=today).annotate(user_points=Sum('pointlog__point_money'))
    users = serializers.serialize('json', users_object)
    return HttpResponse(users, content_type="text/json-comment-filtered")
```

This code passes json data very well its own objects.

But not include 'user_points' which is from annotate.

How can I include it?

Comment: Can you also show your serializer?

Comment: I'd **strongly** suggest you use [DRF][1].
If you want to avoid that, declare your [fields][2]


  [1]: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/
  [2]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields

Comment: @Dalvtor Unfortunately I don't use DRF.

Comment: @JulienKieffer It looks like delare model fields. Can I add annotate's variable in field=() ?

Comment: @Miguel It's supposed to work, but I didn't try.